# Finale: How can I enter triads using only the keyboard with Speedy Entry?

Tags: software, finale

I've got a copy of Finale SongWriter 2014 and I'm wondering if it's possible to enter chords (in my specific case, triads) using only the keyboard. The Speedy Entry keyboard makes notating things go exponentially faster than using a mouse, but I'm not sure I see a way to do chords. The problem is that after I've entered the first note in the chord, when I go back to it pressing Up or Down on the keyboard merely moves the existing note rather than adding a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the song writer works the same as Finale proper. By speedy entery from unison to octave use number 1 - 8 (key row), from second and below shift 2 - 9 .
EDITION: this for Microsoft only Mac could be something else.
This is a link to download a quick reference card [here](http://makemusic.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5683/~/finale-2014.5-quick-reference-guide---access-from-help-menu-%28windows%29)

Comment: It does appear to be the same! Holding Shift and pressing number keys on the number row (instead of the NumPad) added the extra notes. Thanks!

Comment: That is going down the intervals with the shift button. Up the intervals is number's 1 - 8 ( row number's)